# how to create a new source set for specific build types

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, multi-module

So, i'm learning multi module and utilizing build types for different purposes. And think of using another source set for specific testing. So, i create a build type named `r8_testing` on `:app` and my `:source:impl`.

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

        create("r8_testing") {
            initWith(buildTypes.getByName("release"))
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
    }
```

Then, i proceed with creating source set like what i found on the internet.

```
sourceSets.create("r8_testing") {
        java.setSrcDirs(listOf("src/r8_testing/java"))
        resources.setSrcDirs(listOf("src/r8_testing/java"))
    }
```

But, i got an error from gradle saying

```
Cannot add a AndroidSourceSet with name 'r8_testing' as a AndroidSourceSet with that name already exists.
```

When i try check if i can make the source set by the guide of [Google](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#sourcesets), i cannot find the r8_testing source set to add.